# Passing textfield text value Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

i have three viewcontrollers in signing up for users,
 and i want to pass my textfield values from button to another viewcontroller's button for there to finish the registration. i tried everything that i know but no luck

here is my button from firstViewController

```
@IBAction func nextButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

   let parameters:Parameters=[
       "name":nameTextfield.text!,
       "phone":phoneTextfield.text!
   ]
 }
```

and here is thirdViewController's button action

```
    @IBAction func registerButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    //Sending http post request

    Alamofire.request(URL_USER_REGISTER, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON {
        response in
        //printing response
        print(response)

        //getting the json value from the server
        if let result = response.result.value {

            //converting it as NSDictionary
            let jsonData = result as! NSDictionary

            //displaying the message in label
            //self.labelMessage.text = jsonData.value(forKey: "message") as! String?
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's your problem getting the text from the `UITextField` using the `text` property?

Comment: yes.do you know how to do it? im stuck here for a day.

Comment: Search for how to pass data between view controllers

Comment: What are you getting when you change te text in your text field and get the text using nameTextField.text??

Comment: yes. and using the parameters "name" and "phone" so i can send http post request. please help me :(

Comment: Store "name" and "phone" value in global variable and access it in third viewController or pass it in every viewController by creating property in another controller.

Comment: @MehulSojitra i did what you said. here is what i did in firstViewController -         let destination2 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "uploadProof") as! UploadProofViewController
        destination2.namePassed = nameTextfield.text! as String
        destination2.phonePassed = phoneTextfield.text! as String

Comment: @MehulSojitra and  i set a variable in thirdViewController like this -    var namePassed = String()
    var phonePassed = String()                                                           and put it in the button action like this - let parameters: Parameters=["email":emailPassed, "password":passwordPassed, "phone":phonePassed, "name":namePassed,"username":userNamePassed]
        print(parameters)        # #my question is why is there nothing inside those parameters.?

Comment: Declare class variable with email, password or whatever you want.             public class func instantiateThirdViewController(param1: String, param2: String, param3: String) -> ThirdViewController? {
        let viewController: ThirdViewController = UIStoryboard.proofs().instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ""uploadProof"") as! ThirdViewController
       viewController.param1 = param1
        viewController.param2 = param2
        return webviewController
    } call this method from whatever view controller that you want. It should work fine.

Comment: @JohnKennethParalejas Have you passed value from 2nd viewController to 3rd viewController? And have you checked passed value in 2nd view controller(name and phone), whether its getting proper value or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these steps

1.Create a model with static variables

```
import Foundation

class Model
{
    static var textA:String?
    static var textB:String?
    static var textC:String?
}
```

2. assign the value to the model when your click the button

```
Model.textA = textField.text!
```

3. Access the value from third ViewController

```
 let parameters:Parameters=[
       "name":Model.textA!,
       "phone":Model.textA!
   ]
```

Comment: wow.it worked! thankyousomuch! :) ive been stuck here for a day.